# Proper way of sorting array list

Tags: arrays, sorting, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi guys i'm having a problem on my logic in sorting my sizes list, I hope you can helped me on this one. Here's my approach

In my template file:

```
<div class="collapse show" id="filters-<?= $filter['header'] ?>" aria-expanded="true">
    <?php foreach ($subFilters as $subFilter): ?>
        <?php if (!empty($subFilter['header'])): ?>
            <div class="sub-heading">
                <h3><strong><?= $subFilter['header'] ?></strong></h3>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
    // My Sorting approach
    <?php
        if ($filter['header'] == 'Size') {
            $temp = [];
            $sorted = Configure::read('Products.Sizes.size');

            foreach ($sorted as $key => $value) {
               foreach ($subFilter['options'] as $k => $val) {
                  if ($subFilter['options'][$k]['data']['title'] === $value) {
                      $temp[$key] = $subFilter['options'][$k];
                 }
               }
           }
           $subFilter['options'] = $temp;
       }
    ?>
     <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

In my app.php

```
return [
    'debug' => $debug,
    'DebugKit.forceEnable' => $debug,
    'Products' => [
        'giftCardCode' => '1135069',
        'Skus' => [
            'giftCardCode' => '1660620',
        ],
        'Sizes' => array(
            'size' => [
                '7-8', '8', '9-10', '10', '11-12', '12', '13-14',
                '32A', '32B', '32C', '32D', '34A', '34B', '34C', '34D', '34DD', '36A', '36B', '36C', '36D', '36DD', '38A', '38B', '38C', '38D', '38DD', '40A', '40B', '40C', '40D', '40DD', 
                '32', '34', '36', '38', '40', '42', '44', '46', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', '2XL', 'XXXL'
            ],
        )
    ]
];
```

What i want to do here is to sort it based on the order on the list, which is I did but the problem on my logic is that you will override values in $temp[$key] if 2 or more filter options have the same title. Coz there are sizes that are both different to male and female.

Note: I have a sizes on my database this size list is just a guide so if i want to change something i just need to change on my configuration file.

Comment: try ```$temp[$key][] = $subFilter['options'][$k];```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble assembling the provided code into any testable so I can't provide a very specific solution. 

However, consider using PHPs SPLHeap classes for your sorting. I've always found the documentation of the SPL classes pretty thin but the Heap classes have some useful user contributed notes. For example https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splheap.php#93930

In a nutshell, your heap class extends one of the three SPLHeaps, defines a compare() method then you insert() each value into the heap object. Sorting done.

Comment: To better understand your problem I would need to have more clarity on the structure and possible content of other key variables $filter and $subFilters